# Check to see if none of the checkboxes was checked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have two checkboxes and one of the checkboxes must be checked. I can see that it's right, no syntax errors. What should be made to my code to check if none of the checkboxes were checked?

HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" value="aa" class="first" name="a"> Yes<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="bb" class="second" name="b"> No <br/>
<button type="submit">Go!</button>
<p class="error"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    if( $(".first:not(:checked)") && $(".second:not(:checked)") ){
        $('.error').text('You must select atleast one!');
    }else
        $('.error').hide();
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/ptbTq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using selectors which do not return boolean values which is what you need when writing an `if` condition. Here's what you could do:

```
$('button').on('click',function() {
    if(!$(".first").is(":checked") && !$(".second").is(":checked")) {
        $('.error').text('You must select atleast one!').show();
    } else {
        $('.error').hide();
    }
});
```

or if you prefer and think it could be more readable you could invert the condiciton:

```
$('button').on('click',function() {
    if($(".first").is(":checked") || $(".second").is(":checked")) {
        $('.error').hide();
    } else {
        $('.error').text('You must select atleast one!').show();
    }
});
```

Also notice that you need to `.show()` the error message in the first case as you are hiding it in the second.

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ptbTq/5/).

Comment: I don't approve this solution as this will only work for pre-defined checkboxes with a predefined class. If he wants to add checkboxes later on, the solution fails.

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/692Dx/

Checking code:

```
if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0) {
    alert('none checked');   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the same class on both checkboxes and you can do something like

```
if ($(':checkbox.the_class:checked').length > 0) {
  // at least one checkbox is checked
  // ...
}
```

Comment: but i have many different checkboxes on my page that's why i have called them with their class names.

Comment: This is only true if 2 or more is checked.

Comment: Then you should put the same class to both and check $(':checkbox.the_class:checked').length. Right @AndreasAL I changed my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Short:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")
```

returns `true` if:

one of your checkboxes - from the selector (`"input[type=checkbox]"`) - is checked.

else return `false`

and in your case:

```
$(".first, .second").is(":checked")
```

Do something at least one of your checkboxes is checked

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to put your checkboxes inside a div with an unique ID so you can verify all the checkboxes in there, so your code will work in all cases. Even when adding new checkboxes to the div later on.

```
<div id="cb">
   <input type="checkbox" value="aa" class="first" name="a" /> Yes<br/>
   <input type="checkbox" value="bb" class="second" name="b" /> No <br/>
   <button type="submit">Go!</button>
   <p class="error"></p>
</div>
```

Your JQuery:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var checked_one = $('div#cb input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked');

    if (!checked_one )
        $('.error').text('You must select atleast one!');
    else
        $('.error').hide();
});
```

Live demo can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/ptbTq/15/